# How would I get the right result in this query?

Tags: mysql

I am supposed to make a query that selects "netapa" the id of the table from the ones that do not start in the same city where it ended, it should only show "1, 2, 4, 6" however I don't get how, I have the values below and the query I made as well

Table

```sql
create table etapa
(
  netapa int not null,
  km     int,
  salida varchar(20),
  llegada varchar(20),
  dorsal int,
  constraint PK_etapa Primary Key(netapa),
  constraint etapa_ciclista Foreign Key (dorsal) references ciclista(dorsal) on delete cascade on update cascade

);
```

Values

```sql
insert into etapa values(1,35,'Valladolid','Ávila',1);
insert into etapa values(2,70,'Salamanca','Zamora',2);
insert into etapa values(3,150,'Zamora','Almendralejo',1);
insert into etapa values(4,330,'Córdoba','Granada',1);
insert into etapa values(5,150,'Granada','Almerìa',3);
insert into etapa values(6,150, 'Aragon','Aragon',1);
```

Query

```sql
select distinct netapa
from etapa
where llegada not like salida ;
```

However It's showing me everything but the one that starts and finish in the same city in the same data row, how do I compare distinct data rows?
Thank you!

Comment: Which column is llegada? Which column is salida? See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Salida is the first varchar, llegada the second one.

Comment: See the accepted answer at the linked question, and edit yours accordingly.

Comment: Done, Already added the table as well for further reference, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: should only show "1, 2, 3,6" - I disagree based on the wording of the question only 6 should be excluded since that is the only row where llegada and salida are the same..

Comment: The question says "Select the value of the attribute netapa of the etapas which do not start in the same city where the last one ended"

Comment: That's a very different question and should return 1,2,4,6 not 1,2,3,6

Comment: Yeah, I made a monkas there, but yeah, thanks, I'll edit rn

Comment: what is your version of mysql please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following query, it may help you achieve what you exactly want :

```
SELECT
     e1.netapa
FROM etapa e1
     LEFT JOIN etapa e2 ON e1.netapa = (e2.netapa+1)
WHERE e1.salida <> e2.llegada OR e2.netapa IS NULL
ORDER BY e1.netapa
```

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c3bf0ff4e4a7cc113080ff192b2dd64)